# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"]([^'"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Getting the error as showed in the title.

```
/**************************/
/* Facebook Support      */
function get_fbimage() {
global $post;
if ( !is_single() ){
    return '';
}
$src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), '', '' );
$fbimage = null;
if ( has_post_thumbnail($post->ID) ) {
    $fbimage = $src[0];
} else {
    global $post, $posts;
    $fbimage = '';
    $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i',
    $post->post_content, $matches);
    if(!empty($matches[1]))
        $fbimage = $matches [1] [0];
}
if(empty($fbimage)) {
    $fbimage = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID);
}
return $fbimage;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'remove_add_to_cart_buttons', 1 );

function remove_add_to_cart_buttons() {
  if( is_product_category() || is_shop()) { 
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
  }
}

/**************************/
```

The page says the error is on line 158 which is here:

```
...
$output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i',
...
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you are escaping single quotes in regexp use double backslashes:

```
$output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\\'"]([^\\'"]+)[\\'"].*>/i',
```